# Установка пакета livewires на python 3.5 в windows 8

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Устанавливаю livewires для python 3.5 (pip3, setup.py, качал с [гитхаба](https://github.com/livewires/python) - без разницы каким образом, результат тот-же), установка проходит успешно, но при импорте `livewires` выпадает одна и та же ошибка:

```
>>> import livewires
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\py\LiveW\livewires\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from beginners import *
ImportError: No module named 'beginners'
```

Проверил в установленных либах:
**__init__.py** импортирует `beginners`, **beginners.py** лежит в том же каталоге что и **__init__.py**.

Собственно вопрос: как правильно установить livewires чтобы его можно было нормально импортировать?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, этот модуль `beginners.py` написан на *Python 2*, а у него немного другой синтаксис чем у *Python 3*. Поэтому если попробовать запустить модуль `beginners.py`, он выдает ошибку синтаксиса на выражении `raise`. Если Вам этот пакет нужен для дальнейшего чтения книги Майкла Доусона, можете посмотреть в моей [статье](https://pydoc.livejournal.com/710.html), как я установил его.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Ссылки недостаточно. Вы её завтра уберёте  и этот ответ станет бесполезным. Вы не автору вопроса отвечаете, а всем, кто найдёт вопрос через поиск.

Answer (score 1):

на данный момент существует переформатированная версия пакета LiveWires под названием SuperWires.

Для выполнения упражнений в книге, достаточно заменить LiveWires на SuperWires.

[Скачать данный пакет можно перейдя по этому адресу](https://pypi.org/project/SuperWires/)